# Java Spring Many To Many relation - index out of bounds, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for Hibernate's PersistentSet

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I'm building a simple app using java spring.

I'm having and issue trying to build up a many-to-many relation.
I have following entities:

**User**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  ...

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
  private Set<AssignedItemUser> assignedItemUsers = new HashSet<AssignedItemUser>();
  ...
}
```

**Item**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "items", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "slug" })})
public class Item {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item")
  private Set<AssignedItemUser> assignedItemUsers = new HashSet<AssignedItemUser>();
  ...
}
```

And a join table:

**AssignedItemUser**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "new_assigned_item_users")
public class AssignedItemUser {
  @Id
  private BigInteger id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  User user;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
  Item item;
}
```

When I test the association on an item side - it works. f.ex.

```
item.getAssignedItemUsers().size() //101
```

However, on a user side -  I get an error:

```
user.getAssignedItemUsers().size()
/// ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException@132 "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3"
```

Forgive me being stupid, but I couldn't find anything helpful overt the internet, stacktrace is not helpful either.

Am I doing something wrong? I can't really spot what I am missing here.

Edit :
so I called `printStackTrace()` on the exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
  at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.EnumJavaType.fromInteger(EnumJavaType.java:178)
  at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.EnumJavaType.fromOrdinal(EnumJavaType.java:195)
  at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.convert.internal.OrdinalEnumValueConverter.toDomainValue(OrdinalEnumValueConverter.java:52)
  at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.convert.internal.OrdinalEnumValueConverter.toDomainValue(OrdinalEnumValueConverter.java:29)
  at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.basic.BasicResultAssembler.assemble(BasicResultAssembler.java:80)
  at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.DomainResultAssembler.assemble(DomainResultAssembler.java:33)
  at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.extractConcreteTypeStateValues(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:1037)
  at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.initializeEntity(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:831)
  at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.initializeInstance(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:787)
  at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.coordinateInitializers(StandardRowReader.java:152)
  at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.readRow(StandardRowReader.java:97)
  at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:178)
  at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33)
  at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:443)
  at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:166)
  at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:91)
  at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31)
  at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.CollectionLoaderSingleKey.load(CollectionLoaderSingleKey.java:121)
  at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:789)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
  at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1710)
  at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.lambda$initialize$3(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:617)
  at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:265)
  at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:615)
  at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:136)
  at org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:295)
```

As it is calling `EnumJavaType` it may be worth noting, that both Item, and User model have enum fields, but there is no enum field on AssignedItemUser.

---

Finally, the root cause of the issue, turned out to be an integer db column, mapped to an enum, on java end. As values in the column were not consecutive (0, 2, 3) it didn't match ORDINAL enum type on java end. Adding a converter resolved the issue.

Comment: I would still encourage to provide more lines from stacktrace. Are you sure the error comes from the line which is calling .size() ?

Comment: i am guessing you are trying to access the index of the same value as length (in this case 3).  For length 3 indexes are `0 1 2`. That is how indexes in arrays and lists work. So to access the last element you need to use `size()-1` and stop there.

Comment: @fascynacja I attached screenshots with backtrace, let me know if it helps.
@JAsgarov it's not that, I get the error when I try any of those methods:

`isEmpty(), size(), toArray(), toString()`

Comment: this is very badly presented question missing all the information that is actually causing the issue. ManyToMany and Spring is completely irrelevant here it is a simple IndexOutOfBounds exception. This exception can't happen from `size()` call, only when you actually try to access element of the collection.

Please don't use screenshots, paste formatted console log of the exception. If you paste the actual STACKTRACE you will see which line or method it was

Comment: @adkra do you have a Exception Stack Trace which tracks all the method being called? What you posted is informative but still not enough.

Comment: @fascynacja I eventually got one, edited the question. Let me know if it helps, or more is needed. I don' t want to take too much of your time.
(btw stacktrace is much longer I assumed that what's deeper is probably irrelevant)

Comment: @fascynacja thanks for your help, I think I see what happens. So to explain, the item has enum field, that can have a one of 3 values. I defined a java enum for it.
However DB I work with is a legacy, so it is not just `0, 1, 2`. Values in db column are `0, 2, 3`. I will try adding a converter, and see if it helps.

Comment: I hope it will solve your issue, you can add this enum into the code, which you posted. In that way someone with similiar problem in the future will see where could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone faces a similar issue, here's what worked for me:

Reading stack trace, first row is:

> at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.EnumJavaType.fromInteger(EnumJavaType.java:178)

the item entity has an attribute:

```java
  @Column
  private ItemAvailability availability;
```

Which is an Enum:

```java
public enum ItemAvailability {
  ALL,
  SELECTED,
  HIDDEN
}
```

What I missed is that the column in database stores one of 3 values: `0, 2, 3`. Mind you, they are not consecutive.

Therefore, I added a Converter:

```
public class ItemAvailability implements AttributeConverter<ItemAvailability, Integer>{
...
}
```

And this eventually resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to make it work:

```
    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ItemAvailability availability;
```